# powershell - filter the result of FL

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to filter the result of an automatic `FL`.

for example, `Get-ADUser someuser -Prop *` returns tons of lines in list format and I'm only interested in those containing some text, whatever the field is. for example, the lines containing `True` or those containing `foo`.

I'm in no way interested in getting the resultant lines in a variable or do further processing on the corresponding field, but just filter the displayed lines on screen, à la `grep`

do you have any clue for me ?

PS. I'm stuck with PS v2 for this one.

Comment: Use `where-object` against the `Get-Aduser`. Perhaps with select-object to get the fields you want. __DONT filter text from `FL`__. It breaks objects. You are just making it harder

Comment: Moreover if you run this command with `-Property *` on a lot of accounts if will be very slow. Are you sure you don't know what fields you search in ?

Comment: usually, I do that when I do know the value is available somewhere, potentially in multiples fields but I don't know in which one(s). as I said, I'm not interested in doing further processing on the corresponding fields. at least not directly. filtering the output reveals the potential fields name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found a very easy way of searching PS output :)

```
Get-ADUser someuser -Prop * | Out-String -Stream | Select-String foo
```

hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an interesting problem. One way to do this would be to pipe the output to a file. For example:

```
Get-ADUser someuser -Prop * > tmp
Select-String -pattern "(True|foo)" -path tmp | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
Remove-Item tmp
```